# Using Pandas, want to group by multiple columns for min/max and add another column value to min/max columns

Tags: pandas

First of all, sorry if the title is hard to understand.

Target:
I'm trying to group by `source, type` columns, add the `min,max`  columns for each group by result
,and then add the related `target` column to both `min` and `max` columns (in front of the value).

I can't figure out how to get the Pandas result in this format:

| source | type | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person1 | bow | Person 2: 0.001 | Person 3: 0.05 |

I have a list of dictionaries as followed:

```
`[{'source': 'Person1', 'target': 'Person2', 'type': 'bow', 'similarity': 0.636}, {'source': 'Person1', 'target': 'Person2', 'type': 'bigram', 'similarity': 0.040}, {'source': 'Person1', 'target': 'Person2', 'type': 'tfidf', 'similarity': 0.433}, {'source': 'Person1', 'target': 'Person3', 'type': 'bow', 'similarity': 0.699}, {'source': 'Person1', 'target': 'Person3', 'type': 'bigram', 'similarity': 0.171}, {'source': 'Person1', 'target': 'Person3', 'type': 'tfidf', 'similarity': 0.522}]`
```

In table from this looks like:

| source | target | type | similarity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person1 | Person2 | bow | 0.636 |
| Person1 | Person2 | bigram | 0.040 |
| Person1 | Person2 | tfidf | 0.433 |
| Person1 | Person3 | bow | 0.699 |
| Person1 | Person3 | bigram | 0.171 |
| Person1 | Person3 | tfidf | 0.522 |

For the group by, min/max I'm using the following:

```
df = df.groupby(['source','type']).similarity.agg(['min','max'])
```

Which results into:

| source | type | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person1 | bow | 0.636 | 0.699 |
| Person1 | bigram | 0.040 | 0.171 |
| Person1 | tfidf | 0.433 | 0.522 |

All good to this point, but how do I get the output into the following structure:

**[Source]**:source;**[Type]**: type; **[min]**: Target:min(similarity); **[max]**: Target:max(similarity)

| source | type | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person1 | bow | Person2: 0.636 | Person3: 0.699 |
| Person1 | bigram | Person2: 0.040 | Person3: 0.171 |
| Person1 | tfidf | Person3: 0.433 | Person3: 0.522 |

Am I supposed to use .loc to find the row for the min / max values and then somehow add those to the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach with [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html#) and [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) :

```
g = df.groupby(by=['source', 'type'], sort=False)
​​
out = (
            pd.merge(df.loc[g['similarity'].idxmin()]
                       .rename(columns= {'similarity': 'sim_min', 'target': 'target_min'}),
                     df.loc[g['similarity'].idxmax()]
                       .rename(columns= {'similarity': 'sim_max', 'target': 'target_max'}),
                     on=['source','type'])
              .assign(min=lambda x: x.pop('target_min') + ': ' + x.pop('sim_min').astype(str),
                      max=lambda x: x.pop('target_max') + ': ' + x.pop('sim_max').astype(str))
        )
```

Another variant :

```
g = df.groupby(by=['source', 'type'], sort=False)
​
​
out = (
            pd.merge(df.loc[g['similarity'].idxmin()]
                         .assign(min= lambda x: x[['target', 'similarity']]
                                                     .astype(str).agg(": ".join, axis=1)),
                     df.loc[g['similarity'].idxmax()]
                         .assign(max= lambda x: x[['target', 'similarity']]
                                                     .astype(str).agg(": ".join, axis=1)),
                     on=['source','type'], suffixes=('', '_'))
                .loc[:, ['source', 'type', 'min', 'max']]
      )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

    source    type             min             max
0  Person1     bow  Person2: 0.636  Person3: 0.699
1  Person1  bigram   Person2: 0.04  Person3: 0.171
2  Person1   tfidf  Person2: 0.433  Person3: 0.522
```

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
data = [['Person1', 'Person2', 'bow', 0.636],
        ['Person1', 'Person2', 'bigram', 0.04],
        ['Person1', 'Person2', 'tfidf', 0.433],
        ['Person1', 'Person3', 'bow', 0.699],
        ['Person1', 'Person3', 'bigram', 0.171],
        ['Person1', 'Person3', 'tfidf', 0.522]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['source', 'target', 'type', 'similarity'])
```

`df`

```
    source  target  type    similarity
0   Person1 Person2 bow     0.6
1   Person1 Person2 bigram  0.0
2   Person1 Person2 tfidf   0.4
3   Person1 Person3 bow     0.7
4   Person1 Person3 bigram  0.2
5   Person1 Person3 tfidf   0.5
```

**Process**

```
df.groupby(['source','type']).agg([min, max])
```

result:

```
                target              similarity
                min     max         min     max
source  type                
Person1 bigram  Person2 Person3     0.0     0.2
        bow     Person2 Person3     0.6     0.7
        tfidf   Person2 Person3     0.4     0.5
```

make result to your desired output

Add `:`  to value of target column of df, change value of result to str, and combine them.

**Full Code and Output**

```
(df.assign(target=df['target'] + ': ')
 .groupby(['source','type']).agg([min, max]).astype('str')
 .groupby(level=1, axis=1, sort=False).sum().reset_index())
```

output:

```
    source  type    min             max
0   Person1 bigram  Person2: 0.04   Person3: 0.171
1   Person1 bow     Person2: 0.636  Person3: 0.699
2   Person1 tfidf   Person2: 0.433  Person3: 0.522
```